# Changing classList results in an Uncaught TypeError Failed to set an indexed property

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to change the classes of multiple siblings upon a click event, some of them might have multiple classes to each, but the class that I intend to change is always the first one, so that is what I came with

```
let classList = event.currentTarget.classList;
    if (classList[0] === 'open'){
      classList[0] = 'close';
      event.currentTarget.classList = classList;
      return;
    }
    let sibllingList = event.currentTarget.parentElement.children;
    for (let i=0;i<sibllingList.length;i++) {
      classList = sibllingList[i].classList;
      if (classList[0] === 'open') {
        classList[0] = 'close';
        sibllingList[i].classList = classList;
        break;
      }
    }
    classList = event.currentTarget.classList;
    if (classList[0] === 'close'){
      classList[0] = 'open';
      event.currentTarget.classList = classList;
    }
```

This worked when I was working with a single class and using className instead of classList, and the function worked fine, but when I switched it to classList, it didn't work and threw the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set an indexed property on 'DOMTokenList': Index property setter is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a read-only property. So, you can't assign the value to it. So, you're getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set an indexed property on 'DOMTokenList': Index property setter is not supported.

You'll need to add the class instead:

```
event.currentTarget.classList.add('close')
```

To remove the class, use remove:

```
event.currentTarget.classList.remove('open')
```

This way you don't need to check for first class name. It will add/remove the required className.

> Note: Removing a class that does not exist does NOT throw an error.

Or, you may just use replace:

```
event.currentTarget.classList.replace('open', 'close')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try have a look

```js
var classList = test.classList;
    if (classList[0] === 'open'){
        test.classList.replace('open', "close");
      //event.currentTarget.classList = classList; // dont need this 
    }
    console.log( test.classList)
```

```html
<div id="test" class="open b test"> <div/>
```